# Keras CIFAR-10 Dense Layer Code Why 512 Neurons in Last Layer?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras to build a CNN to work with the CIFAR-10 dataset. I am slightly confused at one of the last lines of an online tutorial. They take 50,000 32x32 color images and process them through 4 convolutional layers and one fully connected layer. The last part is accomplished by:

```
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
```

I am trying to understand why it is model.add(Dense(512)) and not some other number. For example, I thought 32x32 images can be flattened to a 1024-size vector. But, why did they choose 512 here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualy not 32x32, it's 32x32x3 because of color channels and flatten and dense different methods I think you won't get the code there is low level implementation:

```
W1=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32*32*3,512]),name="W1") #variable
x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[batch,32,32,3])              #placeholder for inputs
flat=tf.reshape(x,[batch,32*32*3])                        #model.add(Flatten())
mul1=tf.matmul(flat,W1)                                   #model.add(Dense(512))
relu=tf.nn.relu(mul1)                                #model.add(Activation('relu'))
```

flat's `shape=[batch,32*32*3]`
mul1's `shape=[batch,512]`

Of course it could be 1024 or 5000 but it becomes harder to optimize.